# quick ifs and pointers in C giving a warning: argument to '&' not really an lvalue; this will be a hard error in the future

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
} point;
```

And I am populating it from stdin as follows:

```
point pts[3];

int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        scanf( "%f", &(j ? pts[i].y : pts[i].x) );
```

However the compiler (GCC) gives me this warning:

> warning: argument to '&' not really an lvalue; this will be a hard
>   error in the future

The line given in the error is:

> scanf( "%f", &(j ? pts[i].y : pts[i].x) );

What is wrong with doing this? Is there a short way to do this using a quick if?

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++? It's an _lvalue_ in C++, but not in C.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'm asking about this in c. But I'm curious about how it differs in C++ too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conditional expression does not return an assignable value, so you cannot take its address. However, you can make a conditional on addresses, like this:

```
scanf( "%f", (j ? &pts[i].y : &pts[i].x) );
```

Now the conditional chooses between two address expressions, so the result is a valid address.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about two different languages. (UPDATE: the question has now been retagged to only ask about C. Ignore this answer if you're not interested in C++.)

In C, the conditional expression doesn't give an *lvalue*, so you shouldn't be able to assign to it or take the address of it. Instead, take the address in each expression:

```
j ? &pts[i].y : &pts[i].x
```

In C++, it does yield an *lvalue* if both expressions have the same (or similar enough) types, so this should be fine. But if you are writing C++, you probably want to use fewer C idioms.

Comment: That's because I'm interested in how it works in both languages my dear friend. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Every operator yields either an l-value or an r-value as its result. `?:` yields an r-values (non assignable values) but not l-values and hence

```
scanf( "%f", &(j ? pts[i].y : pts[i].x) );
```

is wrong. `&` operator operates on l-values.

Comment: quick ifs work different in c than other languages? In Java for example you could do (true ? "yes" : "no") and the String "yes" would be returned. I swear obj-c does the same thing. No love for this functionality in c?

Comment: I don't know about other languages but you can do this in C as `#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int a = 1;
 
 printf("%s", a ? "YES" : "No");
    return 0;
}`.

Comment: And yet you claim `?:` returns a boolean?

Comment: @AlanStokes; True. That was a blunder. Edited my answer